# Is it possible to update Alloy UI to newest version in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui

My current version of Liferay (6.2) has Alloy UI with few bugs.

Those bugs are repaired in newest version of Alloy Ui. Is it possible to use newest version of Alloy Ui instead of the old one?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to not update alloy-ui version but apply patches for bugs.

Comment: I agree with @PankajKathiriya, do not replace AlloyUI but apply fix to it.

Comment: @Daniele Baggio One such [bug](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/AUI-1208) for which I'm currently trying to attain the fix. As of Service Pack 6, I'm still experiencing the issue within my portal. Is Liferay responsible for patching the fix or are there separate patches I should be looking for?

Comment: @Origineil Liferay uses to patch alloy-ui parts. Although If you have EE version you can request a specific patch for this LPS without wait for official hotfix.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possible, but there's a good chance, that you have to do extensive testing before doing it on your production environment and possibly some hand work also will be needed to make it work (if there is major version change, I think it won't work anyway because of the huge changes in the code base).